# как найти индекс массива в матрице

Tags: python

Задание такое,надо сгенерировать матрицу из случайных чисел,потом вывести номер массива в котором больше всего повторяющихся элементов. В чем моя ошибка?

```
from random import randint
    k = 0
    N = int(input())
    M = int(input())
    count = [0]*N
    x = [[0]*N for i in range(M)]
    for i in range(M):
       for c in range(N):
          x[i][c] = randint(1, 10)

    for i in range(M):
       for c in range(N-1):
          if x[i][c] == x[i][c+1]:
             count[k] += 1
       k += 1

    index = 0
    max = count[0]
    for s in range(len(count)):
       if count[s] > max:
          index = count[s]

    print(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых структурная ошибка в программе: список count имеет N элементов:

```py
count = [0]*N
```

Но цикл проводится по M. Если M > N, происходит выход за пределы списка

```py
for i in range(M):
  for c in range(N-1):
    if x[i][c] == x[i][c+1]:
      count[k] += 1
  k += 1
```

Во-вторых логическая ошибка: поиск повторений осуществляется неправильно. Вообще для этого есть масса алгоритмов, но проще воспользоваться функцией `Counter` из стандартной библиотеки `collections`. Она возвращает словарь, где ключ - сам элемент исходного списка, а значение ключа - количество вхождений. Код тогда будет выглядеть так:

```py
from random import randint
from collections import Counter

M = int(input('Введите количество строк > '))
N = int(input('Введите количество столбцов > '))

count = [0]*M
x = [[0]*N for i in range(M)]

for i in range(M):
  for c in range(N):
    x[i][c] = randint(1, 10)

# в целях проверки результата выводим массив, который получился    
print('===== X =====')
for ar in x:
  print(ar)


# проверяем каждый элемент внешнего списка
for i in range(M):
  # с помощью Counter создаём словарь, в котором содержится число вхождений каждого элемента именно для этой строки
  c = Counter(x[i])
  # проверяем словарь
  for key in c:
    # если элемент входит в список больше одного раза
    if c[key] > 1:
      # добавляем число его вхождений
      count[i] += c[key]

# выводим count, чтобы убедиться в правильности
print('=== Count ===\n', count, '\n=============')

# ищем максимум среди count
max = count[0]
for s in range(len(count)):
  if count[s] > max:
    max = count[s]

# выводим найденный максимум
print('Больше всего повторений в ', max, ' строке')
```